# Emmet-mode: Wrapping individual lines in HTML tags

Tags: html, emmet

I'm new to Emacs, new to Emmet, and new to Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to wrap a list of text in individual html tags.

Home
About
Something

is supposed to become

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

Apparently emmet has an abbreviation for this. (Documented here: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/)

Following these instructions, I select my 3 lines of text, hit C-c w to bring up the emmet wrap function, enter ul>li* and hit RET. But instead of the expected

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

I get

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried experimenting with the $# placeholder but that didn't help.

Wraping a selected text in a single tag works fine (select text -> C-c w -> p -> RET to create a p-tag with the selected text in it). Creating multiple tags, each with the same text in it also works fine (select text -> C-c w -> ul>li*3 will create a ul with 3 items, each one has the selected text in it).

Supposedly the * operator (without a number) repeats something for each line highlighted, but that doesn't seem to work. Is this feature not available in Emacs' emmet-mode or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, I don't think [emmet-mode](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode) supports this feature. There are a number of differences between `emmet-mode` and the original Emmet that are not documented. You should [write up an issue](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode/issues/new).

Comment: Will do. (As soon as I get home.)

Comment: Issue [here](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode/issues/81)

Comment: is this issue resolved? i tried wrapping my text file with html tags and it doesn't work.

Comment: Mark the text and type C-c C-c w

Answer (score 0):

It's not `emmet-mode`, but `web-mode-surround` from `web-mode` performs the desired function for any tag (it asks for a tag name in the minibuffer)